# How to select and set a covering/covered annotation as a feature in RUTA

Tags: uima, ruta, dkpro-core

I have a Ruta rule that looks something like this, where dep is a DKPro imported [Dependency](http://dkpro.github.io/dkpro-core/releases/1.8.0/docs/typesystem-reference.html#de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.syntax.type.dependency.Dependency) type.

```
dep{}->{MyItem{->
        SETFEATURE("Display", "displayedValue"),
        SETFEATURE("Lemma", dep.Dependent.lemma.value),
        SETFEATURE("Parent", dep.Governor)};};
```

The first two actions work.  The problem I have is in the third action `SETFEATURE("Parent", dep.Governor)`.  dep.Governor returns a Token type but my feature requires another type that happens to share the same location as the Governor. In other words I want my own type, not dep.Governor, that has already annotated that governing word.

I am unsure how to recover an annotation (my annotation) that occupies the same space as the dep.Governor.  Ideally I would like to recover it as a variable so that I can reuse it for other features to do something like this.

```
a:MyItem [that overlaps dep.Governor]

dep{}->{MyItem{->SETFEATURE("Parent", a)};};
```

Here is a more precise example

```
d:dep.Dependency{->
    MyItem, 
    MyItem.Display = "Ignore",
    MyItem.Lemma = d.Dependent.lemma.value,
    MyItem.LanguageParent = d,                              
};
```

The line MyItem.LanguageParent = d produces this Ruta error

```
Trying to access value of feature "type.MyItem:LanguageParent" as "type.MyItem", but range of feature is "de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.syntax.type.dependency.Dependency"
```

Comment: The rule in your precise exmaple works in my Ruta Workbench. Maybe your problem was already in in some newer version of Ruta.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there is a cleaner way than this, but for now, I am converting the type using a block function and saving it into an annotation variable.

```
BLOCK(ConvertTokenToMyItem) Token{IS(MyItem)} {
    varMyItem:MyItem;          
}
```

Then I use it

```
d:dep.Dependency{->
    MyItem, 
    MyItem.Display = "Ignore",
    MyItem.Lemma = d.Dependent.lemma.value,
    MyItem.LanguageParent = varMyItem,                              
};
```

Comment: I wonder why your example here works since the label is som sort of local variable ahich should not stay assigned between statements. Your rule should work just well without the block. I recommend to use labels at the implicit action: `m:MyItem, 
    m.Display = "Ignore",`

Comment: I use a global variable rather than a local variable and I call the block just before I use it, so that the variable is used immediately.  Thanks for the advice on the labels.  Oh and I note your comment above.  I will experiment to see if I can get rid of the block.